# Vue child inside a parent v-if="false" won't be excuted, but except inside a Modal wrapper with default slot, why?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Please see this minium example

## 1

This minimum template won't throw any error since the parent is not rendering anything.

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="false">
    {{ i.dont.have.the.value }}
  </div>
</template>
```

## 2

Now if I create a Modal wrapper with default slot, and still using `v-if`

#### Modal.vue

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="show">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    show: Boolean,
  },
};
</script>
```

However, this will throw Error, Why?

#### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <Modal :show="false">
    <div>{{ i.dont.have.the.value }}</div>
  </Modal>
</template>

<script>
import Modal from "@/components/Modal.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    Modal,
  },
};
</script>
```

`[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dont' of undefined"`

Why is this happening?

How can I create a Modal with guarantee children won't be excuted if not show?

I can't directly use `v-if` in the Modal component because I need a transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake about the slot in `App.vue` because VueJS will try to resolve your `i.dont.have.the.value` variable based on parent scope (your slot is not conditioned)

Remember this rule from official documentation

```
Everything in the parent template is compiled in parent scope; everything in the child template is compiled in the child scope.
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Compilation-Scope

Just define the variable in the right scope and you will be fine (if you define it in child component and want to expose it to parent, use a scoped slot then).